# How do I insert into a Boost MPL map

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

I manage to use Boost MPL vectors and lists just fine, but I just can't figure out maps. When I try to insert into one, I get "too few arguments" from clang 3.1 (gcc 4.7 says something similar). There is a version of insert where the second argument is POS, which is supposed to be ignored, so I tried inserting a dummy type (int) there, but that just gives a new and confusing error.

```
include <iostream>

#include <boost/mpl/key_type.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace mpl;

int main(){

  typedef pair<int_<3>, int_<6>> obj;

  std::cout << key_type<map<>, obj >::type::value << std::endl; //works

  std::cout << has_key<insert<map<>, obj>::type, obj)::type::value << std::endl; //complains on "too few template arguments for class template 'insert'

  std::cout << has_key<insert<map<>, int, obj>::type, obj)::type::value << std::endl; // gives "implicit instantiation of undefined template 'boost::mpl::insert<..."
}
```

MPL errors aren't exactly helpful, even with clang, so I just don't understand what I am doing wrong here? I am sure it is something silly.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/map.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#include <boost/mpl/insert.hpp>
```

and correct brackets, from ')' to '>'

http://liveworkspace.org/code/afb6632c3eb800412ea551f50c07fb0a

Comment: D'oh, I am an idiot :). I assumed that importing map.hpp imported everything related to map. As an aside, it seems to me that instead of overloading metafunctions for the sequences it would be more natural if the types contained its own methods, like map<>::insert.